# Ionic default push/pop transitions

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, transition

I'm new with Ionic, and i'm learning using the docs.

Saw that i can push a page in the template, like this:

```
<button ion-button [navPush]="pushPage"></button>
```

link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/NavPush/

But i can't find a way to change the transition to left-to-right (like IOS transitions).

How can i change the default transition?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

You can use [**Native Page Transitions**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-page-transitions/) plugin.You need to configure it globally.Then you'll have that transition page animations when you'll use `navPush` on each and every page.

**Old:**

You need to do it like this:

```
this.navCtrl.push(pushPage, {
    animation: true, direction: 'forward'
});
```

> Some methods on NavController allow for customizing the current
>   transition. To do this, we can pass an object with the modified
>   properites.

[image]

You can read more [**about it here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).

Comment: yeah, i saw that. But, i'm trying to use the new way, on the template. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/NavPush/. Since i'll use only this type of animation, i thought i could make it default.

Comment: I don't know why you cannot use mentioned approach with your app? Any reason? You cannot do it only by using `navPush` directive.That is a directive and it has been developed only for one purpose.That is pushing a page.

Comment: Please see my **Update** too.

Comment: Just wanted to add here, use `animate:` instead of `animation:` to comply with `NavOptions` class. In other news, `direction` can be either `forward` or `back`.