# How to disable the animation only in pages transition in ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

i would like to disable page transition animation in Ionic 4, i dont want to use  `IonicModule.forRoot({animated: false});` becouse it disable all the animations of the app such as **skeletons and toasts** i want disablle only for pages

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827903/ionic-default-push-pop-transitions)
It explains 2 ways by achieving this; with a native plugin or by setting an extra option in the navCtrl (which I use in my app)

```
this.navCtrl.push(pushPage, {
    animation: false, direction: 'forward'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm using **ionic 4** and would like to use `routerLink=""` instead **navCtrl** or any way disable it globally

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
this.navCtrl.push(AccountPage, {
  animated : false, 
  animationDirection : 'forward'
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.